# No agent found in pool LinuxAgent which satisfies the specified demands: maven

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I am trying to run my pipeline on Private Hosted agent (Linux). I am using maven as a build tool. However I am getting the below error: kindly assist on it
error :

Agent job 1

##[error]No agent found in pool LinuxAgent which satisfies the specified demands: maven, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.144.0

Comment: According to the error message, obviously your pipeline has added a demand, if the demand is not what you need, you can remove it, Pipelines->edit pipeline-> options. If it is what you need, you need to install maven on your agent to meet the demand.

Answer (score 0):

The error has indicated the issue, there is no "maven" on your build agent machine. You need to do the following items:

1. Upgrade your build agent to the latest version, or configure a new build agent with latest version.
2. Install "maven" on the build agent machine, and you must restart the agent for the new capability to show up in the pool so that the build can run.

Comment: the issue is solved, I installed the maven on agent and added demand in pipeline